# What is the format of degree() output for graph with labeled nodes in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I am using an edgelist to generate a graph with many numbered nodes:

```
library(igraph)
edgelist <- read.table(text="2 3
1 2
1 3
2 4
1 4")
g <- graph.data.frame(edgelist, directed=TRUE)
```

The output of degree() gives two rows, with cols following the order nodes were introduced:

```
deg <- degree(g)
deg
2 1 3 4 
3 3 2 2
```

What is the data structure of this output, and how can I recreate it manually? When I try to create an equivalent table, dataframe or matrix I get extra header rows/cols. (`typeof(deg)` gives "double") My application is graph visualization to use in place of `deg` in `V(g)$size <- deg` (with order of nodes preserved).

Comment: `typeof` is rarely useful. If you really want to know what ab object is use `str()`. If you run `str(deg)` you'll see that it's a named numeric vector. So the names are the vertex names and the value is the degree for the vertex. The `deg` could also be created as `deg <- c(`2` = 3, `1` = 3, `3` = 2, `4` = 2)`

Comment: It would be easier to see how it works if you try edgelist consisting of letters like  A, B, C .....

Comment: Thank you @ThomasIsCoding! The ` symbol was disappearing due to the comment formatting but by doing deg <- c(A=2, B=3, etc.) I see now how to create the data structure in a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MrFlick's comment correctly identified the format as a named numeric vector. While I couldn't get their code to work as written with the grave accent symbol, by looking up the correct data structure I was able to recreate the desired output:

```
deg <- c(3,3,2,2)
names(deg) <- c(1,2,3,4)
1 2 3 4
3 3 2 2
```